# Google data studio table shows date column as null

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm creating a custom community connector for data studio and I'm having an issue with date fields.

If I set the type of the field  `apply_date` to text, I can see it in my table as in the images below:
[image]

[image: Dates shown as strings]

However, when I change the type of the field to date, the date column shows null values.

[image]

[image: dates shown as null]

What am I be missing?

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this? I am getting exactly the same, even with the YYYYMMDD format

Comment: @PhillDuffy, I fixed it by using the `YYYYMMDD` format

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference?hl=en#semantictype), Google data studio only supports dates in the format:`YYYYMMDD` with no separator. After formatting the field like this, the dates are now being shown.