# I want to know an efficient way to link "yyyy-mm-dd" date type data to DataStudio

Tags: date, looker-studio, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can I accept "yyyy-mm-dd" instead of "yyyymmdd" when I put data into a date type column in DataStudio?

From the following Q&A and the official documentation, it looks like "yyyymmdd" only.

[Google data studio table shows date column as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65027185/google-data-studio-table-shows-date-column-as-null)

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6401549?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

However, since the date type of Snowflake, the source of the linkage, only allows "yyyy-mm-dd", the
I'd like to know how to do this efficiently, because I'm changing the date type to a character type, linking it to DataStudio, and then changing it back to a date type in DataStudio.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#date

I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Comment: `However, since the date type of Snowflake, the source of the linkage, only allows "yyyy-mm-dd"` <-- This is not the case. For both input and output, Snowflake can use formattable date and datetime formats. Are you putting data into Snowflake or reading out of Snowflake?

Comment: @GregPavlik  Thank you so much for answering my question.
I want to link my data from SNOWFLAKE to DATASTDIO.
I thought your answer was to make it a character type and in YYYYMMDD format, is that correct?　I would like to use the date type and format YYYYMMDD, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: You can use Mike's answer to convert a date format coming out of Snowflake. For data coming into Snowflake, you can use the to_date function, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html. It will be something like `try_to_date('20210701', 'YYYYMMDD')`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how things are mapped from Snowflake to DataStudio, but Snowflake can produce yyyymmdd dates.

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR('2021-08-19'::DATE, 'YYYYMMDD');
```

If DataStudio requires that the data type from the source be a `DATE` then perhaps you could alter the date_output_format of your connection session or user to be 'YYYYMMDD'.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-date-output-format

Comment: Thank you very much.
I guess I should change the session settings. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Import your data as it is into Data Studio. In the schema screen, ensure your source date field ("yyyy-mm-dd") is formatted as text. Then add a calculated field with the formula:

`TODATE(source_date_field,"%Y-%m-%d","%Y%m%d")`

[TODATE reference](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300?hl=en)

Formate the new calculated field as date.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
When I connect the snowflake data to datastudio, the item (yyyymmdd) is displayed as date type. If I then change it from a date type to a character type on datastudio, it shows up as a number. Do you know how to fix this?

After changing the date type to yyyymmdd in snowflake, I did the following in datastudio and it works fine.

TODATE(source_date_field,"%Y-%m-%d","%Y%m%d")